# Función sumatoria raster

Tags: r

Tengo un ciclo con un serie de imágenes raster y quiero extraer los valores iguales a 150 y luego sumar la cantidad total de pixeles para toda la longitud del ciclo. Con el código que tengo solo logro obtener el total de valores por cada imagen de forma separada y no en forma total. Gracias

```
   m=52419
   for(i in 1:4){
   b1<-raster(myras1[i])
   bc = b1 == 150 #Valores iguales a 150
   nbc = cellStats(bc,stat="sum")
   print(nbc)
   [1] 34962
   [1] 38729
   [1] 52389
   [1] 52176
   pc=nbc*100/m
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin un conjunto de datos de ejemplo para reproducir qué has intentado es difícil proponer una respuesta. Sin embargo, lo siguiente debería ser un punto de partida.

Usamos `sapply` para realizar las operaciones en cada elemento del objeto *myras1*.

```
sapply(myras1, function(elemento) {
  bc <- raster(elemento) == 150
  nbc <- cellStats(bc, stat = "sum")
  nbc * 100 / m 
})
```

Esto nos va a devolver un resultado por elemento. Como, según entiendo, deseas la suma de todos los resultados, puedes entonces hacer lo siguiente.

```
sum(sapply(myras1, function(elemento){
        bc <- raster(elemento) == 150
        nbc <- cellStats(bc, stat = "sum")
        nbc * 100 / m
    }) )
```